Content area not found in my page with Elementor when using shortcode
When I use shortcode of the team showcase plugin in my teams page on WordPress, and published it, then when I open it by edit with Elementor:

Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. You must call the_content function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page.


This message always appears. How can I fix it?
I tried to put wp_reset_postdata(); and the_content() functions in single.php and page.php, but also in vain.

Change the page/post template to Elementor Full Width.

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing! This answer could use some explanation and details, to fit the quality standards here. For example, you could expand on why this would solve the problem and how. Explaining what's causing the current problem is also a good addition. I suggest you take the [tour] and read [ask], before posting more posts. It's better to first understand how this website works, and what's expected of its users, first. This website is very different and unique.
